# How can i get this way to create random data?

Tags: python, numpy, gaussian

I need to create random data using this lines

```
n_samples = 3000

X = np.concatenate((
    np.random.normal((-2, -2), size=(n_samples, 2)),
    np.random.normal((2, 2), size=(n_samples, 2))
))
```

but didn't get the difference between two lines of random here . I got that this way be used to concatenate two random numbers to create 2 clusters but why one of them using (-2,-2) and the other (2,2) and does 2 in this size because concatenate using to merge 2 groups of random data or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing multiple values to either the `loc` or `scale` arguments can be used to generate multiple random distributions at once with different parameters. In the code you provided the values for the `loc` argument are the same, meaning that you could also just use the value `-2` instead of `(-2, -2)`. You can see this when fixing the seed and generating new numbers

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
print(np.random.normal((-2, -2), size=(5,2)))
# [[-0.23594765 -1.59984279]
#  [-1.02126202  0.2408932 ]
#  [-0.13244201 -2.97727788]
#  [-1.04991158 -2.15135721]
#  [-2.10321885 -1.5894015 ]]

np.random.seed(0)
print(np.random.normal(-2, size=(5,2)))
# [[-0.23594765 -1.59984279]
#  [-1.02126202  0.2408932 ]
#  [-0.13244201 -2.97727788]
#  [-1.04991158 -2.15135721]
#  [-2.10321885 -1.5894015 ]]
```

The different between the two lines is that one is generating random noise from a normal (Gaussian) distribution with a mean of -2 and the other from a mean of 2, see also the `loc` keyword in [the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.normal.html).